# Write on android kitkat with xamarin

Tags: android, file, xamarin

Goodmorning i'm trying to writting files and directory on android kitkat but everytime visual studio give me this error:`System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/sdcard/Android/data/test.test/update.txt' is denied`
with android 6.0 i didn't have problems but with kitkat yes.
it's not important where write these files i tried to write in the directory o
`string folder = @"/sdcard/Android/data/test.test/";
            string fileupdate = "update.txt";
            string testPath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim).AbsolutePath;
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(folder) != true)
            { System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folder); }
            else { }
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(folder+fileupdate) != true)
            { StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(folder + fileupdate);
                sw.Close();
            }
            else { }`

Do you know how can i solve this?
regards
andrea

Comment: Writing to this path requires the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, and starting in KITKAT, read access requires the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, which is automatically granted if you hold the write permission.

Starting in KITKAT, if your application only needs to store internal data, consider using getExternalFilesDir(String), getExternalCacheDir(), or getExternalMediaDirs(), which require no permissions to read or write.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html

Comment: I solve using file.write and file.read or i write under the application path but under files.thanks andrea